# Select and Update with join giving different records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, inner-join

I have two table with relation

- Table Assignment
- Table Tickets

There is a field in assignment table which is status. So I am fetching record from table assignment where status is `complete` that returns `6909 records`

Than I return records using inner join with condition of status `complete` that also return `6909` records.

But when i update table using join and with same condition that update `6625` records not `6909` . Is there is any problem with query or anything else? Kindly guide

Queries:

First : return 6909 records

```
SELECT * FROM [ITSC].[dbo].[assignment] where assignment_status = 'Completed'
```

Second : return 6909 records

```
SELECT tickets.ticket_submitted_by , tickets.ticket_type , tickets.ticket_open_date , tickets.ticket_priority , tickets.ticket_description , assignment.staff_name,assignment.assigned_time_start,assignment.assigned_time_end,assignment.assignment_status
from tickets 
inner join 
assignment 
on tickets.ticket_id = assignment.ticket_id
where assignment.assignment_status = 'Completed'
```

Third : Update 6625 records not 6909

```
 update tickets set tickets.ticket_close_date = '2015-04-29' 
,tickets.ticket_close_time = '2015-04-29 09:25:40.670' from tickets
 inner join assignment
 on tickets.ticket_id = assignment.ticket_id
 where assignment.assignment_status = 'Completed'
```

Comment: check if there are columns that already have the right value .. these are not counted  in update.

Comment: I have reset both columns with NULL , It still updating 6625 records

Comment: Check if there are cases where a specific ticket has more than one assignment. If there are, that ticket will be counted twice in the `select` but probably only once in the `update`...

Comment: @user1429080 Thanks ..Yep that was the reason i wrote query using distinct and it return 6625 not 6609 ..

Comment: @Replynot if you want to make sure after update try the "second" select it should give you 6909 records.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this query

```
 update tickets set tickets.ticket_close_date = '2015-04-29' 
                    ,tickets.ticket_close_time = '2015-04-29 09:25:40.670' 
    from assignment
    where  tickets.ticket_id = assignment.ticket_id
    and  assignment.assignment_status = 'Completed'
```